# Overlay module does not work

Tags: 7, updating, modal-dialogs

I updated my Drupal, but now the overlay module does not worki and everything shows on the center of page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a temporary problem.

do these steps:

1-disable overlay module.

2-click on **Save configuration** at the end of page.

3-click on modules again

4-enable overlay module **Save configuration**

> ```
> its like reseting a computer
> ```